# Open and Post to a tab page using C#

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am able to post to a page using open graph api and c#. But how do I post in a tab-page??

Answer (score 0):

Page tabs are are just apps that are installed on pages. You can "post" to them at `graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID`.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Via the API you can add/remove tabs from pages. You can give them a custom name and icon.

Comment: I am trying to do this, using graph api explorer tool. But i am getting error "(#210) Subject must be a page."

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/

I add field as, app_id=APP_ID and access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs?app_id=app_id&method=POST&access_token=page_access_token -> returns true, but nothing is added. 

i checked it with https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs